# show popup message OpenERP V6

Tags: python, popup, odoo

I want to display a popup message box when a function is called in OpenERP V6.

Answer (score 0):

```
raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), ('Event'))
```

is used for raising exception/error dialog in a particular model which usually in a form / a tree / a wizard